# Java8 Optional with Function chaining expression

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8, option-type

I am wondering is there a way to simplify the following code ? I am trying to get something from database by using EBean. If there's something then map it to an object or otherwise return the default implementation instance.

```
public static ObjectA test1() {

    Function<Optional<SqlRow>, ObjectA> sqlRowToObjectA= new Function<Optional<SqlRow>, ObjectA>() {
        @Override
        public AccountSummary apply(Optional<SqlRow> entry) {
            return entry.isPresent() ? new ObjectA(entry.get().getInt("id"), entry.get().getString("name"))
                 : ObjectA.EMPTY;
        }
    };

    return sqlRowToObjectA.apply(Optional.of(Ebean.createSqlQuery("select * from table1").findUnique()));
}
```

Comment: I think you can map the entry into newly created object, or else return en empty element.

Comment: @MiserableVariable easier to understand and could be done with maybe like a chaining fashion ?

Comment: define easier to understand

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a lambda instead of an anonymous class - and use map to get the desired result + orElse for the default value:

```
Function<Optional<SqlRow>, ObjectA> sqlRowToObjectA =
    entry -> entry.map(e -> new ObjectA(e.getInt("id"), e.getString("name")))
                  .orElse(ObjectA.EMPTY);
```

However, in your example, you don't need a `Function` at all and could rewrite the whole method like this:

```
public static ObjectA test1() {
  SqlRow row = Ebean.createSqlQuery("select * from table1").findUnique();

  return Optional.ofNullable(row)
                 .map(e -> new ObjectA(e.getInt("id"), e.getString("name")))
                 .orElse(ObjectA.EMPTY);
}
```

Note that because `findUnique` may return `null`, you should use `Optional.ofNullable()` rather than `Optional.of()`: the latter will throw an exception if the row is `null`.

---

And finally, I would add that it would be simpler and more efficient to write:

```
public static ObjectA test1() {
  SqlRow row = Ebean.createSqlQuery("select * from table1").findUnique();

  return row == null ? ObjectA.EMPTY
                     : new ObjectA(row.getInt("id"), row.getString("name"));
}
```

or change the method signature and let the caller decide what to do if there is no result:

```
public static Optional<ObjectA> test1() {
  SqlRow row = Ebean.createSqlQuery("select * from table1").findUnique();

  return Optional.ofNullable(row)
                 .map(e -> new ObjectA(e.getInt("id"), e.getString("name")));
}
```

Comment: and the last line (the return) would look the same ?

Comment: Yes, a Function is a Function... But you could skip the function altogether and call map on `Optional.of(Ebean.createSqlQuery("select * from table1").findUnique())` directly.

Comment: so map can be used like an "If" with orElse ?

Comment: `map` converts an SqlRow into an ObjectA if the optional has a value - otherwise `orElse` is called to create an empty ObjectA. I suggest you read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) for more details.

Comment: this is cool and elegant...thanks

Comment: Note that there is still a logical error: `Optional.of(…)` never returns an empty optional, so if that’s an intentional use, using `Optional` is completely unnecessary here. If, on the other hand, it’s supposed to handle a possible `null` returned by `findUnique`, then you must use [`Optional.ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-). @assylias maybe it’s better to include a complete usage example that doesn’t use this obsolete `sqlRowToObjectA` function and does the initial `Optional` creation right.

Comment: Just one last remark. `map`…`orElse` is more than an `if`…`else` equivalent. It can even replace a nested `if` statement, as, when the mapping function returns `null` (can’t happen here), the result will be an empty optional leading to the `orElse` value.

Comment: @Holger you mean I can do something like Ebean.createSqlQuery("select * from table1").findUnique().map(..).orElse() without having this Optional wrapper ?